# How to properly back reference symbols in executable from dll?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I'm writing a Qt program, which dynamicly loads plugins. But the plugins require the class declared in the main program. I tried to include the headers in the library and add `-export-dynamic` for program linker, which work quite fine on linux.

However, MSVC toolchains seems don't have such option. The build failed because of the missing of classes' vtable and metaObject. If I add the headers to the library (that let moc to process the header), it still failed for missing implemention of classes' methods.

I've search some questions. They suggest making the main program be a dll, or use dllexport/dllimport for all the classes. And I'm not sure if this work for those things generated by moc. In my opinion, it would cause redefinition.

Is there a better way to solve it? Or is there a best practice for this problem?

---

Main Program:
class A, B, C

Plugin:
class P which need to process A, B and C

Comment: Move your common functionality into an own dll.

Comment: Please explain why you think that moc-generated stuff can't be placed in a DLL. Show what you've tried and what failed.